# In pinescript alerts is there any way to detect what the timeframe of the chart and then send alerts based on that?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I have a tradingview indicator through which I send alerts to discord, the alerts are like this

```
msgr1=syminfo.ticker + ',' + timeframe.period + ', Crossed Resistance 1'


if srLines==true and close > h10
    alert(msgr1)
```

The problem is `timeframe.period` sends alerts in multiples of 60, so if timeframe of the chart is 2 hours it sends 120, and 3 hours is 180, and so on. This is confusing to interpret for discord members, so I thought that if I could detect if `timeframe.period` is under a 1 day period then I could return timeframe after doing its modulus with 60

So I tried to do this

```
if timeframe.period < 1D
    timeframe=timeframe.period%60
else
    timeframe=timeframe.period
msgr1=syminfo.ticker + ',' + timeframe+ ', Crossed Resistance 1'


if srLines==true and close > h10
    alert(msgr1)
```

This does not work, but is there any way I can code this in pinescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string timeframe = na

if timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier >= 60
    timeframe := tostring(timeframe.multiplier / 60) + "H"
else if timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier < 60
    timeframe := tostring(timeframe.multiplier) + "m"
else
    timeframe := timeframe.period
```

Comment: As of Pine Script V5 this needs to be `str.tostring()` for it to run.

Answer (score 0):

on Pine Script V5

```
// Convert timeframe
string timeframe = na

if timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier >= 60
    timeframe := 'H'+ str.tostring(timeframe.multiplier / 60)
    timeframe
else if timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier < 60  
    timeframe := 'M'+ str.tostring(timeframe.multiplier)
    timeframe
else
    timeframe := timeframe.period
    timeframe
```

alert() formet is
alert('text', freq )

```
alert('text, (' + timeframe + ') | ' + syminfo.ticker + ': '+ str.tostring(close, "#.#####") + '\n text \n text ', alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

use \n for a new line

```
text, (H4) | BTCUSD: 48194 
text 
text
```

enjoy..